# Looking for web-browser with web-based user interface

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a web browser with a web-based user interface. Considering that this sounds strange and exotic, let me briefly describe my use-case:

- I'm using Jupyter notebooks (comparable to Matlab) for scientific computations which run on a cluster (Linux). Jupyter itself has a web-based user interface (only).
- In these notebooks, I write Python code. After having opened a notebook in my web browser, the computations can run without any necessity for leaving the browser open.
- However, due to Jupyter's software design, the output of the computations isn't updated in the notebook, as soon as the browser is closed. This means that for very long computations I always have to keep the browser open and the computer on, despite that the computations are running on a remote cluster and the browser is only needed for input & to view the results.

This is where a web browser with web-based user interface would come into play: Instead of interacting with Jupyter directly through the web browser on my computer, I could *interpose* that hypothetic web browser like a *proxy*.

So, does anybody know whether a web browser with a web-based user interface exists for Linux?

Comment: Could you open a VPN or Remote Desktop session into one of the cluster computers, so you can run things in there and disconnect leaving the window open in the remote computer?

Comment: @fernando.reyes I could, if there was a graphical user interface, but unfortunately it only supports terminal-based access via SSH.

Comment: I don't really understand what you say about the proxy.  How exactly would you use this?  Are you saying you want to run a program on the server/cluster which would connect to the jupyter server like a browser, and then wait for you to access it from your own computer using a regular web browser?

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, that's what I am saying. Maybe you can also think of it (the hypothetic proxy-like web browser with web-based user interface) like a super-lightweight virtual desktop, which only offers a web browser.